# Prove that $f(M)=f^2(M)$ implies $f(M)$ is a direct summand of $M$ whenever $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a reduced ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, projective-modules, injective-modules

Let $M$ be a right $R$-module with the property that every homomorphism $\gamma:Sf\to M, f\in S=\text{End}_R(M)$, extends to $S\to M$.   If $S$ has the property $f^2=0$ implies $f=0$ for every $f\in S$, then prove that $f(M)=f^2(M)$ for every $f\in S$ implies $f(M)$ is a direct summand of $M$.

In trying to solve this problem, I obtain the following:  Note that $M$ is $(S,R)$-bimodule.
$f(M)=f^2(M)$ for every $f\in\text{End}_R(M)$ implies $M=\ker(f)+f(M)$. It remains to prove that $\ker(f)\cap f(M)=0$.  Let $x\in \ker(f)\cap f(M)$.  Then $x=f(m)$ for some $m\in M$ and $0=f(x)=f^2(m)$.  From here I have failed to use the hypothesis to convince that $0=f(m)=x$.